# SSH: Login method using Server's Private Key instead of Client's Public Keys?

Tags: linux, ssh, private-key

Just like `AWS EC2` style, how do i setup the way people SSH into my Server to be via the Server's Private Key *(PEM?)*, instead of we uploading Clients Public Keys into Server?

Idea is to share the Server's Private Key (.pem?) to the Clients, so that whoever has that key would be straight away able to SSH into Server. So that there would be no overheads for me (as Server Admin) whenever there are new Client Users/Machines appeared.

That would also mean, as long as we have that Key, we can connect to Server from "any" Client Machines even it is a new one. *(That also would probably allow us to go for the vacation without carrying the Particular Laptops, as long as we have the KEY and a random Computer. :D)*

How to achieve that (AWS-like) method please?

Comment: And how about security? Sure you can add the same public key to the everyone's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and then populate the same private key among the users, but all the responsibility for unauthorized access will be only your.

Comment: I just wanted to achieve the way AWS done. They give us the PEM key. And as long as we have that key, we can SSH from any Client Machine.

Comment: You already have the answer in your question.